# How can I refer to a field being referred by the SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables, `Ongoing_Portfolio` and `Ongoing_Fees`. `Ongoing fees` contains a `foreign key` for `Ongoing-Portfolio`. Below are the tables

[image]
[image]

Please have a look at the below code

```
SELECT Ongoing_Portfolio.*, 
Ongoing_Fees.Ongoing_Net_Income FROM Ongoing_Portfolio 
INNER JOIN Ongoing_Fees ON Ongoing_Fees.idPortfolio = Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio 
WHERE Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio = 1 
AND 
Ongoing_Portfolio.idOngoing_Portfolio = ?
```

Can you see the `?` mark there in the last row? What I wanted to do there is to refer the `idOngoing_Portfolio` field of the `Ongoing_Fees` which is being refereed by the query at the moment. In more detail, I need something like below.

```
 AND 
    Ongoing_Portfolio.idOngoing_Portfolio = idOngoing_Fees of the Ongoing_Fees table where the query is currently accessing
```

How can I do this in mysql?

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is to put the column in as you described it:

```
SELECT op.*, 
Ongoing_Fees.Ongoing_Net_Income
FROM Ongoing_Portfolio op INNER JOIN
     Ongoing_Fees onf
     ON onf.idPortfolio = op.idPortfolio 
WHERE op.idPortfolio = 1 AND 
      op.idOngoing_Portfolio = onf.idOngoing_Fees;
```

Does this do what you want?  If not, you might consider asking another question.  Putting the actual `create table` statements is more useful than a picture of two tables.  Sample data and desired results are a big help both for you to understand what you want to do and to convey this information to others.